# How can I create a table like this?

Tags: tables, overleaf

I found this table on a paper and wish to use in my work as a reference. The thing is I don't know how to configure it so it looks like this...The topics on each column are not the same size and are not aligned, and I don't know how to make them  "work independently". Can someone help me please?[image]

Comment: Are the columns going to span pages? Does the style of paragraphs (space between them, no indentation, etc.) match the rest of the document? You could either do this as a table with just one row that uses a column specifier that allows paragraphs, or you could do it with columns using something like the multicol package.

Comment: Please place the code what you tried so far, no one likes to key the text...

Answer (score 1):

Using table may not be the right approach for those kind of structures.

For longer documents, I'd suggest one of the two environments: `multicols` (from [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol)) or `paracol` (from [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol)), which split a part of a document into a number of columns. There are differences, though.

The first environment causes text to flow continuously from left column to the right. Then on the next page it starts again from the left column etc. This is similar to the option `twocolumn`. In the second environment, whatever is added to either column is controlled by `\switchcolumn`, which in its trivial form simply cycles between columns.

With only short texts, two environment give the same output

[image]

However, the outcome is different when the extra content is added in the middle. On the left page, the other section (Right) is pushed downwards and the arrangement is no longer as expected. On the right page, the right section remains in place because arrangement is controlled by `\switchcolum`.

[image]

In the end, `multicol` is almost always the right choice unless a more sophisticated structure is required.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength\columnsep{2em}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{The environment: \texttt{multicol}}]
  \subsection{Left}
  \kant[1][1-4]
  \kant[2][1-2]

%  \subsection{In-between}
%  \par\kant[5][1-3]

  \subsection{Right}
  \kant[3][1-3]
  \kant[4][1-2]

  \raggedcolumns
\end{multicols}

\clearpage
\section{The environment: \texttt{paracol}}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \subsection{Left}
  \kant[1][1-4]
  \kant[2][1-2]

%  \subsection{In-between}
%  \par\kant[5][1-3]

  \switchcolumn
  \subsection{Right}
  \kant[3][1-3]
  \kant[4][1-2]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```